# Sort sequence from distinct values

Tags: xpath-2.0

What is the cleanest way to sort a sequence I get from `distinct-values()`? I use XPath 2.0 and my files are the following:

This is my XML file

```
<root>
  <value>3</value>
  <value>1</value>
  <value>7</value>
</root>
```

and this is my transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <output>
      <xsl:variable name="availableValues" select="distinct-values(value)"/>
      <!-- now the availableValues contains the sequence (3,1,7) -->
      <!-- My goal is to get this into a sorted sequence (1,3,7) -->


      <!-- This is just for testing the $availableValues -->
      <xsl:attribute name="count" select="count($availableValues)"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$availableValues">
        <val>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </val>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tried to use

```
  <xsl:variable name="availableValues">
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(value)">
      <xsl:sort/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
```

but this (of course) doesn't give me a sequence, just the concatenation of the values (although sorted).

### EDIT:

This is what I came up so far, and it looks like a proper solution. Is there a better solution?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  >
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <output>
      <xsl:variable name="availableValues" as="xs:integer *">
        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(value)">
          <xsl:sort/>
          <xsl:sequence select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>    
      </xsl:variable>

      <!-- This is just for testing the $availableValues -->
      <xsl:attribute name="count" select="count($availableValues)"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$availableValues">
        <val>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </val>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [xsl:perform-sort](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/xsl-elements/perform-sort.html).

Here is an example from the link:

```
<xsl:perform-sort select="//BOOK">
    <xsl:sort select="author/last-name"/>
    <xsl:sort select="author/first-name"/>
</xsl:perform-sort>
```